# What c++11 paradigm should I use to minimize memory-usage and minimize copying?

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, interface, ownership

**PROBLEM**

I have an abstract interface `Series` and a concrete class `Primary_Series` which satisfies the interface by storing a large `std::vector<>` of values.

I also have another concrete class `Derived_Series` which is essentially a transform of the `Primary_Series` (eg some large `Primary_Series` multiplied by 3), which I want to be space-efficient, so I do not want to store the entire derived series as a member.

```
template<typename T>
struct Series
{
  virtual std::vector<T> const& ref() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Primary_Series : Series<T>
{
  std::vector<T>  m_data;
public:
  virtual std::vector<T> const& ref() const override { return m_data; }
}

template<typename T>
class Derived_Series : Series<T>
{
  // how to implement ref() ?
}
```

**QUESTION**

*How should I change this interface/pure-virtual method?*

I don't want to return that vector by value because it would introduce unnecessary copying for `Primary_Series`, but in the `Derived_Series` case, I definitely need to create some kind of temporary vector.  But then I am faced with the issue of how do I make that vector go away once the caller is done with it.

It would be nice if `ref()` would return a reference to a temporary that goes away as the reference goes away.

Does this mean I should use some kind of `std::weak_ptr<>`?  Would this fit with how `Primary_Series` works?

*What is the best approach to satisfy the "minimize memory usage" and "minimize copying" requirements, including making the `Derived_Series` temporary go away once the caller is done?*

Comment: Is the `derived_series` meant to be sort of a lazy transform of the `primary_series`? And if so, do you want to make the programmer responsible for keeping the reference non-dangling? If so, I would suggest either reference or ptr. However I would recommend `shared_ptr` inside the `derived_series` and `primary_series`, that points to the data. Then you will however need to solve the problem with transforming the data... So I don't think you can properly (ie. efficiently and lazily) implement the interface as given. Is there a reason you want to use this interface instead of implementing ...

Comment: a subscript `[]` operator, `at()` function or iterators over the series?

Comment: @Xarn yes, a lazy transform is exactly what I am looking for, but is there a way I can make the `derived_series` one go away once the caller is done with it?  I just saw your second comment - that may be even better as it hides the implementation better and it shifts the responsibility of cleanup totally to the caller.  I think I can accept that as an answer if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll write it up with a bit less "rambling" style and will elaborate a tad bit more..

Comment: @Xarn I just realized that with a subscript operator or with at(), in the `Primary_Series` case, I would end up making an entire copy, so I'm effectively back to return-by-value, unless I am not understanding your meaning correctly.

Comment: I don't see it: `T& at(std::size_t pos);` returns a proper reference without copying, or `const T& at (std::size_t pos);` returns a proper const reference without copying. Where it gets dicey is `Derived_Series`, where you will have either return by value, or make some hacky work to keep things working properly (Basically constrain yourself to input iterators that masquerade as RA iterators, or some temporary storage for a transform (and throw it out later), etc.) Other thing you can do is to at each evaluation of the lazy range fill in a permanent range, but that brings with itself whole

Comment: different world of pain and tradeoffs. (Did I mention that C++ doesn't do lazy easily? :-) )

Comment: You might want to look into fusion lib from boost, it provide concept of views.

Comment: @marcin_j doh - I have been using boost spirit with a tiny bit of fusion while coding up a domain-specific-language, but I didn't know about views.  I will look into it now, but if you have some time to elaborate in an answer - not sure if a fusion view is related to what I'm trying to do here, but I will read up.  Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Well the interface design as it is poses a bit of a problem, because C++ doesn't really do lazy.

Now, since `Derived_Series` is supposed to be a lazily-evaluated (because you want to be space-efficient) transform of the original `Primary_Series`, you cannot return a reference of a full, fat vector. (Because that would require you to construct it first.)

So we have to change the interface and the way the `_Series` share data. Use `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<>>` to share the data between the `Primary_Series` and `Derived_Series`, so that `Primary_Series` going out of scope cannot invalidate data for your transform.

Then you can change your interface to be more "vector-like". That is, implement some (or all) of the usual data-accessing functions (`operator[]`, `at()`...) and/or custom iterators, that return transformed values from the original series. These will let you hide some of the implementation details (laziness of the transform, sharing of data...) and still be able to return transformed values with maximal efficiency and let people use your class as a "vector-like", so you don't have to change much of your design. (~Any algo that uses vector will be able to use your class after being made aware of it.)

**[I've also sketched out a very basic example of what I mean.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23cc77ddafcb2b09)**

*(Note: If you have a multithreaded design and mutable `Primary_Series`, you will have to think a bit about where and what you need synchronized.)*

---edit---
*After mulling it over a bit more, I also have to note that the implementation for `Derived_Series` will be kinda painful anyway. It's methods will have to return by value and its iterators will basically be input iterators masquerading as higher class of iterators, because return by reference for lazily evaluated values doesn't really work, or it will have to fill in it's own data structure, as the positions for the original series is evaluated, which will bring with it completely different set of tradeoffs.*

Comment: +1 I like your thoughts on the design.  For a simple case of `Derived_Series` with a multiplier of 3 times some instance of another `Series`, what would some of the vector-like implementations actually look like?  Could you add some code to your answer for clarification?  Thank you.

Comment: @kfmfe04 I'll try to throw together a little bit of sample code, but give me some time... ;-) Lately the only coding I've been doing is with old GCC that hasn't even heard of lambdas, functions and such, so I need to figure out things again.

Comment: @kfmfe04 See the link inside the answer for a very basic example.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a `std::shared_ptr<vector<T> >` to store the vector in your base class, and use that to return the value of the vector. The base class just returns its member value, and the derived class creates a new vector and returns that via a shared_ptr. Then when the caller doesn't need the returned value any more for the derived class, it will be automatically destroyed.

Alternatively, you can design your class to mimic the interface of an `std::vector<T>`, but design the base class so it returns the transformed values instead of the regular values. That way, no return is ever necessary. If you don't want to write methods for all of the functions a `std::vector<T>` has, you could just make some sort of transforming iterator that can iterate over and transform a `std::vector<T>`. Then you don't even have to have a complicated class hierarchy.

Comment: So do you mean in the `Primary_Series` case, there are two shared_ptr - one as a member and one returned by the function call (of course, both pointing to the same vector), whereas in the `Derived_Series` case, there is only one returned by the function call?  I think that might work.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define your own `iterator` and make your `vector<T>` private. Basically, you will have pure virtual accessors to `begin()` and `end()`. And the `Derived_Series` will just wrap the iterator of the `Primary_Series` and transform values on the fly.